# Go wash vs Get washed

Tags: grammar

Is there a significant difference between these two sentences? which one is more appropriate when we have to tell our kid to wash his hands before having food.

1. Go and wash your hands
2. Go and get your hands washed

How these two sentences are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally never heard (2) (at least, for the verb *to wash*), but I would say (1) is more recommended, because it is more straight-forward and thus sends out the message clearer and faster.

Also, I would lose the *and* there, so it looks like this:

> Go wash your hands.

Comment: _Go wash your hands_ is the American usage; British English would use _and_. Sentence (2) _could_ be understood to mean _have your hands washed by someone else_, but in fact _get [a task done]_ is often used colloquially when giving orders to a child.